# XPath to return string concatenation of qualifying child node values

Tags: xpath, string-concatenation

Can anyone please suggest an XPath expression format that returns a string value containing the concatenated values of certain qualifying child nodes of an element, but ignoring others:

```
<div>
    This text node should be returned.
    <em>And the value of this element.</em>
    And this.
    <p>But this paragraph element should be ignored.</p>
</div>
```

The returned value should be a single string:

```
This text node should be returned. And the value of this element. And this.
```

Is this possible in a single XPath expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**In XPath 1.0:**

You can use

```
/div//text()[not(parent::p)]
```

to capture the wanted text nodes. The concatenation itself cannot be done in XPath 1.0, I recommend doing it in the host application.

Comment: Thanks - you're absoluately right. I just read the XPath reference and discovered that all string functions implicitly work on the first node in a node-set, so there's consequently no way to combine selection and concatenation.

Comment: Lovely and elegant. Good on you!

Answer (score 29):

**In XPath 2.0** :

**`string-join(/*/node()[not(self::p)], '')`**

Comment: But nested function is not supported in string-join()  like string-join(normalize-space(//a[@class="title"]//text()))

Comment: @SIslam, It is not a "nested function" problem, but just that `normalize-space()` takes a single argument -- not a sequence. You can use this expression instead: `string-join(//a[@class='title']/normalize-space())` . Of course, you must add a second argument to the call of `string-join()`

Answer (score 6):

This look that works:

Using as context `/div/`:

```
text() | em/text()
```

Or without the use of context:

```
/div/text() | /div/em/text()
```

If you want to concat the first two strings, use this:

```
concat(/div/text(), /div/em/text())
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a good step in the right direction. But I can't see how to concatenate the results. When I wrap this in a call to the string() function, it only returns the value of the first selected node.

Comment: Yes, and, as you could see, my solution does the same as the "correct" solution.. ¬¬
You can concat(...) nodes, but, you wont see the third "text".
Try this: 

concat(/div/text(), /div/em/text())

Answer (score 6):

```
/div//text()
```

double slash forces to extract text regardless of intermediate nodes

Answer (score 0):

If you want all children except p, you can try the following...

```
    string-join(//*[name() != 'p']/text(), "")
```

which returns...

```
This text node should be returned.
And the value of this element.
And this.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this comes a bit late, but I figure my answer could still be relevant. I recently ran into a similar problem. And because I use `scrapy` in Python 3.6, which does not support xpath 2.0, I could not use the `string-join` function suggested in several online answers.

I ended up finding a simple workaround (as shown below) which I did not see in any of the stackoverflow answers, that's why I'm sharing it.

```
temp_selector_list = response.xpath('/div')
string_result = [''.join(x.xpath(".//text()").extract()) for x in temp_selector_list]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

You could use a for-each loop as well and assemble the values in a variable like this

```
<xsl:variable name="newstring">
    <xsl:for-each select="/div//text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Not relevant. Poster asked about XQuery.