# How to extract a text from multiple tags with Xpath (lxml)?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Let say I have code like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>Date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='something'>
   <td>8 september</td>
   <td>2008</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to extract the date to have "8 september 2008".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1405439/181772

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath to return string concatenation of qualifying child node values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403971/xpath-to-return-string-concatenation-of-qualifying-child-node-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A pure XPath 1.0 solution.**

**Use:**

```
string(normalize-space(//table/tr[@id = 'something']))
```

Comment: Amazing. If I will have "<tr id='something'>...</tr>" 30x, how to get 30x the string from it?

Comment: @acheruns: If you have this node 30 times, then with only XPath 1.0 it isn't possible to get all required strings. You'd have to evaluate the XPath expression 30 times in a loop (from 1 to count(expression)), each time with a different index. `string(normalize-space((//table/tr[@id = 'something'])[$k])) `  --- where `$k` has to be substituted by a number from 1 to `count(//table/tr[@id = 'something'])`

Answer (score 1):

You could collect the text from each `td` element, and join them with `' '.join(...)`:

```
import lxml.html as LH

content = '''
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>Date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='something'>
   <td>8 september</td>
   <td>2008</td>
  </tr>
</table>
'''

doc = LH.fromstring(content)
date = ' '.join(td.text for td in doc.xpath('//table/tr[@id = "something"]/td'))
print(date)
```

yields

```
8 september 2008
```

Or, if you can handle the carriage returns, you could use the `text_content()` method:

```
for td in doc.xpath('//table/tr[@id = "something"]'):
    print(td.text_content())
```

yields

```
8 september
   2008
```