# How to return category with its sub-categories which are on the same level?

Tags: xml, xpath, hierarchical-data, xpath-1.0

How I can select list of categories with its sub-categories' values using XPath (1.0 preferably)?

The structure is like:

- category (1)

  - name (1)
  - value (1-1)
  - value (1-2)
- category (2)

  - name (2)
  - value (2-1)
  - value (2-2)
  - value (2-3)
- etc.

So ideally I need to a return list of a categories' names with their associated values, like:

- `name` (1): `value` (1-1), `value` (1-2)
- `name` (2): `value` (2-1), `value` (2-2), `value` (2-3)
- etc.

or ideally:

- `name` (1) / `value` (1-1)
- `name` (1) / `value` (1-2)
- `name` (2) / `value` (2-1)
- `name` (2) / `value` (2-2)
- `name` (2) / `value` (2-3)

  which I expect to be `/characteristics/category/[concat(name/uk, "/", value/uk)]`-like, but the syntax is not correct,

or any similar format as far as I could differentiate main categories from sub-categories, so I can parse that data further using appropriate backend language.

Basically I'm looking to achieve association between categories and its sub-categories in order to store them in a hierarchical taxonomy vocabulary.

I've the following XML from the feed:

```
<characteristics>
  <category id="1">
    <name>
      <uk>Orientation</uk>
      <es>Orientación</es>
    </name>
    <value id="1">
      <uk>North</uk>
      <es>Norte</es>
    </value>
    <value id="2">
      <uk>East</uk>
      <es>Este</es>
    </value>
    <value id="3">
      <uk>South</uk>
      <es>Sur</es>
    </value>
    <value id="4">
      <uk>West</uk>
      <es>Oeste</es>
    </value>
  </category>
  <category id="2">
    <name>
      <uk>Condition</uk>
      <es>Estado</es>
    </name>
    <value id="1">
      <uk>Recently Refurbished</uk>
      <es>Renovado Recientemente</es>
    </value>
  </category>
  <category id="3">
    <name>
      <uk>Pool</uk>
      <es>Piscina</es>
    </name>
    <value id="1">
      <uk>Private</uk>
      <es>Privada</es>
    </value>
  </category>
  <category id="4">
    <name>
      <uk>Climate Control</uk>
      <es>Climatización</es>
    </name>
    <value id="1">
      <uk>Fireplace</uk>
      <es>Chimenea</es>
    </value>
  </category>
  <category id="5">
    <name>
      <uk>Views</uk>
      <es>Vistas</es>
    </name>
    <value id="1">
      <uk>Sea</uk>
      <es>Mar</es>
    </value>
    <value id="2">
      <uk>Mountain</uk>
      <es>Montaña</es>
    </value>
    <value id="3">
      <uk>Panoramic</uk>
      <es>Panorámicas</es>
    </value>
  </category>
  <category id="6">
    <name>
      <uk>Features</uk>
      <es>Caracteristicas</es>
    </name>
    <value id="1">
      <uk>Guest Apartment</uk>
      <es>Aprtmnt. Huéspedes</es>
    </value>
    <value id="2">
      <uk>Guest House</uk>
      <es>Casa de Huéspedes</es>
    </value>
    <value id="3">
      <uk>Barbeque</uk>
      <es>Barbacoa</es>
    </value>
  </category>
</characteristics>
```

Here is the XPath query which returns values from the first category:

```
/characteristics/category[@id=1]/name/uk | /characteristics/category[@id=1]/value/uk
<uk>Orientation</uk>
<uk>North</uk>
<uk>East</uk>
<uk>South</uk>
<uk>West</uk>
```

now how do I combine, compare or back-reference those two `id`'s and make it dynamic to work for each category?

**Any idea how to generate such XPath query?**

I've also tried different combinations of `../..`, `parent::`, `ancestor::`, `[]` like expressions and conditions, but without success. I've also tried using [`string-join`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1405439/55075), but it doesn't work in this [demo](http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester), secondly the code where I'm trying to parse it [doesn't support](https://www.drupal.org/node/1510776#comment-5811286) XPath 2.0.

Alternatively the closest/similar selection/format which would allow me to list and differentiate different categories' names with their associated values, so I can parse that structure further in different language?

---

Other tries:

- `concat(/characteristics/category[@id=@id]/name/uk, "/", /characteristics/category[@id=@id]/value/uk)`

  returns only first element: `Orientation/North` (`[@id=@id]` is not needed)
- `concat(/characteristics/category/*/*[name()="uk"]/node(), /characteristics/category)`

  creates some hierarchy which I don't understand (what kind of format it is):

  ```
  Orientation
        Orientation
        Orientación

        North
        Norte

        East
        Este

        South
        Sur

        West
        Oeste
  ```

  but only for the first main category

Comment: Why is the XPath you have used in your question not sufficient?

Comment: @lambo477 I think, because I don't know which one is the main category and which are sub-categories of it. In other words, in backend language parsing such result, I won't able to generate hierarchy from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath is for selection, not manipulation.  You can select nodes as they appear in the input XML document; you cannot re-arrange those nodes arbitrarily, especially with XPath 1.0.  If you want to rearrange nodes, use XSLT or another language from which you call an XPath library.

**Update:** Even after your comments and the update to your question, you're still hanging on to the notion that the result of the XPath 1.0 evaluation can be something more than a ***list of nodes*** selected from the input XML document.  Wanting a hierarchy rather than a list is an indication that you're expecting too much of XPath 1.0.

**Final update...**

### XPath 2.0 Solution

**Given your input XML, this XPath 2.0 expression:**

```
for $c in //category 
    return for $v in $c/value 
               return concat($c/name/uk, ' / ', $v/uk)
```

**will yield**

```
Orientation / North
Orientation / East
Orientation / South
Orientation / West
Condition / Recently Refurbished
Pool / Private
Climate Control / Fireplace
Views / Sea
Views / Mountain
Views / Panoramic
Features / Guest Apartment
Features / Guest House
Features / Barbeque
```

**as requested.**

Answer (score 0):

The most closest XPath 1.0 query would be:

```
characteristics/category/*/*[name()="uk"]/text()
```

which will return flat list of items:

```
Orientation
North
East
South
West
Condition
Recently Refurbished
...
```

And it will returns all items in the correct order (both main and sub categories), however without any hierarchy.

The downside is that the hierarchy needs to be detected and managed somewhere else. For instance, in Drupal CMS I did import of such XML feed into *Taxonomy terms*, so after I manually arranged the hierarchy of the items, the next imports using existing names would keep such hierarchy.