# Omit child nodes when selecting a node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

How do I select nodes without including any child nodes in my select?

For example:

```
 <Result>a
  <subresult>1
  </subresult>
 </Result>
```

From the above code when I select the result node I get the following output:

a1

I am interested in the following output:

a

Comment: dor example, so `normalize-space(/Result/text())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath to return string concatenation of qualifying child node values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403971/xpath-to-return-string-concatenation-of-qualifying-child-node-values)

Comment: Can you please show the code you are currently using to select the "Result" node?

Comment: What do you mean by "selecting" a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `a` is part of a text child node of the `Result` element so if you want the `a` but not the `1` then you want the text child nodes but not any descendant text nodes. As the question is tagged as XSLT 2.0, you should be able to use `<xsl:value-of select="/Result/text()" separator=""/>`. With an XSLT 2.0 processor and `version="2.0"` this will output the string values of all text child nodes, thus if there is e.g. `<Result>a<subresult>1</subresult>b</Result>` you would get `ab`.